# Looking for a jquery continuous image scroller

Tags: jquery, image, scroll, continuous

I'm looking for a horizontal jquery image scroller that I can used to display a large list of logos.

I was able to find almost exactly what I needed here : http://kiusso.net/scripts/imageScroller_jquery_plugin/index.htm

The only problem with this example is that when I implement it the scrolling kept speeding up and slowing down because the logos in my list that I'm trying to display are different dimensions.

Does anyone know how I could fix this problem so the scrolling was always the same speed, Or does anyone know of another image scroller similar to the one in the above link.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the plugin I mentioned in the my question.

My work around was that since the logo's aren't going to be be changing anytime soon. I just created 1 large .jpg containing all the logos spaced evenly. Since there was only one image file I didn't run into the different speeds based on image dimensions issue I was having.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Not sure if it will solve your issue but is quite adaptable

Answer (score 0):

http://www.huntingground.freeserve.co.uk/main/mainfram.htm?../imagery/imgscroll3h.htm

continues slider.. when images end then it start again without pause